# Facebook ads campaign not displaying app installs results data

Tags: android-studio, facebook, sdk, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-ads

Facebook ads campaign not displaying app installs data. I regularly post Facebook ads for my Android app in Play Store. My Facebook ads campaigns are not showing any data for columns like Results, Mobile App install, Cost per app install. I want to track the app installs from the ad clicks. It just shows a dash '-' line instead.I followed Facebook's instructions but it didn't work (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started). I hope you can support me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gSSW.png).

I followed Facebook's instructions but it didn't work (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started). I hope you can support me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gSSW.png).